# How to create a new row using ng-if in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a new row after 10 elements in my list. Following is the code but I am not getting the desired result.

```
<div class="row">                                    
    <div class="col-sm-1" ng-repeat="q in questions">
         <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="select_question(q)">{{ $index + 1 }}</button>
         <br ng-if="$index/10 == 0">                                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="select_new_question()">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure what mistake I am making?

Comment: The [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) is a percent `%` character.

Comment: Do you mean generating this entire <div class="row">                                    
    <div class="col-sm-1" ng-repeat="q in questions">
         <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="select_question(q)">{{ $index + 1 }}</button>
         <br ng-if="$index/10 == 0">                                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="select_new_question()">+</button>
    </div>
</div> once ng-repeat loop for 10 times.

Comment: I tried the % but still did not help. Yes I want to split the row after every 10 elements.

Comment: `$index` is 0 based, so you would want `($index + 1) % 10 === 0`.  With that said, there are very few good places to use the `<br>` tag.  You're much better off styling your html with classes, so I would use a `ng-class` to get what you want.

Comment: Try to use `ng-show` instead, also it is better to use CSS if you just want to style your rows.

Comment: Can you suggest me as an answer??

Comment: HI Shashishekhar, I have posted my answer, try it.

Comment: <div class="row">                                    
    <div class="col-sm-1" ng-repeat="q in questions">
 <br ng-if="$index == 10">     
         <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="select_question(q)">{{ $index + 1 }}</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="select_new_question()">+</button>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: do you want to create pagination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XUApX4bOkxiw3df7iEje?p=preview)

```
<div class="row">                                    
<div class="col-sm-1" ng-repeat="q in questions">
     <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="select_question(q)">{{ $index + 1 }}</button>

     <div ng-if="($index+1)%10 === 0">New Row</div>                                        
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="select_new_question()">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append a break after every 10 elements then you have to put 
 statement before button

```
<div class="row">                                    
    <div class="col-sm-1" ng-repeat="q in questions">
 <br ng-if="$index == 10">     
         <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="select_question(q)">{{ $index + 1 }}</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="select_new_question()">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```